# A direct example on $X^*$ is reflexive but the weak topology and weak* topology on $X^*$ are not equal for a normed space $X$.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, reflexive-space

I asked this question [Example on $X^*$ is reflexive but $\sigma(X^*,X)\neq\sigma(X^*,X^{**})$ for a normed space $X$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2818797/example-on-x-is-reflexive-but-sigmax-x-neq-sigmax-x-for-a-no/2818872?noredirect=1#comment5812562_2818872) before. And the answer is to use $X$ is reflexive iff $\sigma(X^*,X)=\sigma(X^*,X^{**})$ to find a normed space X is not reflexive but $X^*$ is reflexive.

But my professor told me that there is an easy example that show $X^*$ is reflexive but $\sigma(X^*,X)\neq\sigma(X^*,X^{**})$ without using the equivalence. Can anyone give me a hint? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you know that a Banach space is reflexive if and only if its dual is reflexive?

Comment: @DanielFischer♦ Yes. But X is not a Banach space.

Comment: The answer by Rhys Steele in the linked answer not only provides ways of finding easy examples, but also provides a proof that they work (which does not depend on the equivalence). I would presume this is what the professor had in mind; perhaps you should ask him and check?

Comment: That's the point, $X$ mustn't be complete, and its completion must be reflexive. And the answer contains an explicit example. Another example is $c_{00} \subset \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$, but really, all examples are in a way the same.